# How can I use resources in ASPX-files?

Tags: c#, resources, asp.net

I use a WebResources.resx to translate all strings in the Web UI. It works like:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1Caption %>" />
```

But if I try to use the onClientClick-Attribute, the string will not be resolved. What's wrong? Or how can I do it right?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
Text="<%$ Resources:WebResources, Button1Caption %>" onClientClick="return confirm('<%$ Resources:WebResources, ConfirmThisClick %>');" />
```

Comment: what appears in the html where the resource should be if you view the source of the generated page?

Comment: In the HTML-Source appears:
<a onclick="return confirm('&lt;%$Resources:WebResources, ConfirmThisClick %>');"...

The first < appears escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is when asp.net is rendering your strings, but one way to fix it would be to set the `OnClientClick` property in the code behind:

```
Button1.OnClientClick = string.format("return confirm('{0}')", WebResources.ConfirmThisClick);
```

Comment: Do you mean String.Format?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the onclick handler in the code-behind

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClick","DoStuff(" + WebResources.ConfirmThisClick =");
```